How to write constraints in systemverilog
typedef struct packed {
    logic [3:0] A;
    logic [3:0] B;
} pkt;


rand pkt [10] p;

How to write constraints to systemverilog so that they are executed simultaneously:

A and B had unique combinations
A and B had repeatable data a random number of times.

For example:
A in the range 0-1
B in the range 0-2
maximum number of repetitions = 3
Result:
A = 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 , ...
B = 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1 , ...

I tried to use:
constraint r {
    foreach (p[i]) {
        p[i].A         inside {[0:1]}; 
        p[i].B         inside {[0:2]}; 

        unique {p[i].A, p[i].B};

    }
}

But for some reason it doesn't work.
And I don't know how to repeat the values. So that "unique " doesn't break.

You need to clarify what you mean by unique. With respect to what?  And what do you mean by repeatable data?

unique - so that all possible combinations of A and B appear first without repetition.
For the range A from 0 to 1 and B from 0 to 1:
A = 0, 0, 1, 1, then repeat
B = 0, 1, 1, 0, then repeat
And now let's add a random number of repetitions of the data:
A = 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, then repeat
B = 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, then repeat

The constraint you wrote says
p[i].A != p[i].B; //same as: unique {p[i].A, p[i].B};

You probably want cyclic random values using randc. Below produce the 6 possible combinations of values for A and B before repeating
module top;
  typedef struct packed {
    logic [3:0] A;
    logic [3:0] B;
} pkt;

  class A;
    randc pkt p;
    constraint r {
        p.A         inside {[0:1]}; 
        p.B         inside {[0:2]}; 
    }
  endclass
  
  A h =new;
  initial repeat(10) begin
    assert(h.randomize());
    $display("%p",h);
  end
endmodule


It's a pity that you can't use "unique".
I actually have more fields in the structure and using 'randc' fields A and B may not change at all now.
How can I make the data repeat a random number of times with randc?
For example, for A from 0 to 2 it could be: 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2

The answer I gave you could produce those results. randc is on the entire struct, not members of the struct.

Then I won't be able to parameterize the maximum number of repetitions.
